# ACF get_field break &lt; &gt; or <>

Tags: wordpress, acfpro

I'm using ACF 5.9.1 and I'm trying to get a simply field text value with this string stored:

*Mydomain.com - Support support@mydomain.com*

When I print the echo of

```html
<?php echo get_field('my_text_field', 'options'); ?>
```

this is what I see:

*Mydomain.com - Support*

and obviously that is what I see on HTML source:

*Mydomain.com - Support support@mydomain.com*

So every string between <> is treated such as an html node.

Is this a normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by myself, I just escaped the string using the function esc_attr.

So to avoid "get_field" function treat <> (with any string inside) as HTML node, you only need to use this way:

```html
<?php echo esc_attr( get_field('my_text_field', 'options') ); ?>
```

And it will be printed properly as plain text.

Comment: I believe `esc_html` is the function you should go with in this case, esc_attr is for html attributes like alt, src and class for example.